# How does gfortran handle unreachable code?

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-optimization, gfortran

Let's consider this Fortran 95 piece of code (let's say it is contained in a file named `main.f95`):

```
module params
    implicit none
    real*4, parameter :: r4_dum = 1
    real, parameter :: r_dum = 1
    logical, parameter :: r32bit = (kind(r4_dum)==kind(r_dum))
    contains
        subroutine print_state
            implicit none
            print*,'r32bit: ', r32bit
        end subroutine print_state
end module

module convert
    contains
        subroutine r32_to_64bit(r4, r8)
            implicit none
            real*4, intent(in) :: r4
            real*8, intent(out) :: r8
            r8 = dble(r4)
        end subroutine r32_to_64bit
end module convert

program test
    use params, only: r32bit, print_state
    use convert, only: r32_to_64bit
    implicit none
    real :: myReal
    real*8 :: work8

    call print_state
    if (r32bit) then
        call r32_to_64bit(myReal, work8)
    else
        work8 = myReal
    endif
end program test
```

As you can notice, the `else` part of the `if (r32bit)` is unreachable. I ran the following:

```
% gfortran -O3 -Wunreachable-code -fdump-tree-optimized main.f95
```

to see if `gfortran` finds the unreachable part and remove the useless branching or not, but this gives a desperately empty output. It seems that `gfortran` doesn't rip off unreachable parts of the code in the present case.

So, my question is the following: what is preventing `gfortran` from detecting this `else` part is useless and getting rid of it?

Comment: @Adrien I don't believe your code is "unreachable." It's just simply wrong because as the error states, your `real myReal` is actually a `real(8)` on a 64-bit machine. A compiler cannot (and should not) be changing incorrect code based on "useless" if branching. I think you can easily imagine how that might completely destroy legacy code libraries recompiled for modern day uses.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll The condition `if (r32bit)` makes the call indeed unreachable. There is no way it could be call if myReal is of kind `real(8)` thanks to the said condition. I'm not asking the compiler to correct an erroneous call, but to not raise an error on a call that will never be executed.

Comment: @francescalus that makes sense. It explains why the compilation fails with the `-fdefault-real-8` option. But it doesn't explain why no elimination is performed when I compile without this option (in which case the code is valid).

Comment: The code is invalid.  => The compiler raises an error. Full stop. What you want to hear more? There is no reason why the elimination should change anything.

Comment: @VladimirF how is the code invalid when `-fdefault-real-8` isn't used?

Comment: But you use it! It is invalid in the moment of compilation with that option!

Comment: @VladimirF please consider reading the question correctly _before_ being aggressive. I understood why it doesn't work with 64bit reals, I also asked why no optimization is performed in the valid case (without the `-fdefault-real-8` flag). Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't explain your problem very well then. *So, my question is the following: what is preventing gfortran from detecting this if branching is useless and getting rid of it (with the nice side-effect of making the code compilable)?*

Comment: @francescalus @VladimirF I've rewritten my question to focus on the valid case. I've also tried with `gfortran -O3  -fdump-tree-optimized main.f95`, but that doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: It shouldn't print anything. Your program has to print `r32bit:  T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My compiler (gfortran 4.7 and 5.3 `-O3 -fdump-tree-optimized`) does the code elimination:

```
main (integer(kind=4) argc, character(kind=1) * * argv)
{
  static integer(kind=4) options.1[9] = {68, 1023, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 31};

  <bb 2>:
  _gfortran_set_args (argc_2(D), argv_3(D));
  _gfortran_set_options (9, &options.1[0]);
  print_state ();
  return 0;

}
```

and prints the correct answer

```
> ./a.out 
 r32bit:  T
```

You cannot expect the optimization to fix invalid unreachable code. The code remains invalid even unreachable.

---

When I add some diagnostics

```
if (r32bit) then
    call r32_to_64bit(myReal, work8)
    print *, '+'
else
    work8 = myReal
    print *, '-'
endif
```

it is still eliminated correctly:

```
test ()
{
  struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.1;

  <bb 2>:
  print_state ();
  dt_parm.1.common.filename = &"dead_elim.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
  dt_parm.1.common.line = 34;
  dt_parm.1.common.flags = 128;
  dt_parm.1.common.unit = 6;
  _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.1);
  _gfortran_transfer_character_write (&dt_parm.1, &"+"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 1);
  _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.1);
  dt_parm.1 ={v} {CLOBBER};
  return;

}
```

and the program indeed prints `+` as its last output.

There is no condition in the final code, it is eliminated.

---

Perhaps you expect `-fdump-tree-optimized` to print something immediately? It doesn't do that, it writes the optimized code to a file. In my case it is named `dead_elim.f90.191t.optimized`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now. I thought `-fdump-tree-optimized` printed its output to the standard output instead of a file... I have the same result as you. Thanks.